# Why is this value zero after ajax call finishes (asp.net mvc 3 and jQuery)?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

Here is my ajax call:

```
  var totalCost = 0;
    function GetTotalCost(start, end, rID) 
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("CalculateTotalcost")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({ start:start, end:end, rID:rID}),
            dataType: 'json',
            processdata: false,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) { totalCost = data; }
//            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { $('.datepicker1').datepicker("hide"); },
//            complete: function (x, y) { $('.datepicker1').datepicker("refresh"); }
        });
    }
```

Here is my function from which I call ajax:

```
 $('.datepicker2').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            firstDay: 1,
            yearRange: '2012:2100',
            beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                var day = date.getDate();
                if (day in alreadyTakenDays) {
                    return [false, '', alreadyTakenDays[day]];
                }
                else return [true, 'IsActive'];
            },
            onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst) {
                alreadyTakenDays = {};
                getEvents(month, year);
            },

            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                var end = dateText.substring(0, 2);
                console.log(end);
                var rID = $('#RoomID').val();
                console.log(rID);
                var startingHole = $('#DateOne').val();
                var start = startingHole.substring(0, 2);
                console.log(start);
                GetTotalCost(start, end, rID);

                document.getElementById('TotalCost').value = totalCost.toFixed(2);

            }
        });
```

After jQuery script is executed I always get **0 for totalCount?**
Why is this happening? What should I Do?
I would like to appoint totalCount to Html.TextBoxFor in ASP.NET MVC 3, that is why I need totalCount. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have success function handler like this to get correct total cost value:

```
function GetTotalCost(start, end, rID) 
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("CalculateTotalcost")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({ start:start, end:end, rID:rID}),
            dataType: 'json',
            processdata: false,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) { totalCost = data;
                                       document.getElementById('TotalCost').value = totalCost.toFixed(2); 
                                     }
        });
    }
```

In  code like this:

```
GetTotalCost(start, end, rID); 
document.getElementById('TotalCost').value = totalCost.toFixed(2);
```

First line cause ajax call, but it does not wait for response and second line is executed immediately. Later, after server responded, `success` callback function is executed. And it will be executed after second line. That is why your total value is wrong - correct value is set to `totalCost` after you update TotalCost input.

Comment: I added the line document.getElementById('TotalCost').value = totalCost.toFixed(2); after totalCost = data; but still the same. What else should i do? Thank you

Comment: Try to add `console.log(data)` before `totalCost = data;` and see what is shown in console (f12 should be enough to open it, in FF you may need to install firebug)

Comment: Ok, this worked so I am marking this as a solution,thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The ajax call is asychronous and hasn't completed when you set the value on your 'TotalCost' text box.

Comment: How to correct his? Can you please help me, I am srtuggling for several hours now

Answer (score 1):

Because your post is asynchronous and you are trying to set a js variable that is global to the page.  Create a function that sets the variable and call it from the call back, then you will see the result.

Comment: Where will I put the function? I am total begginer to jQuery, thank you

Answer (score 1):

That is because of **Asynchronous ajax** Request..

By the time you the event is handled , the request has not been completed yet.

Welcome to the wonderful world of AJAX.

Comment: @TunAntun FAngel's solution is the way you would need to fix it. All code that needs totalcost needs to be inside of the success callback.